# Enable Debugging Bluez Fedora

Tags: debugging, fedora, systemd, bluez

I work with Bluez on Fedora and need some more debugging information then provided by enabling debugging with "bluetoothd -d". So in best case i want to write in the sourcecode of bluez for debugging. Is it only possible with build bluez new after that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -d flag is the only option to get more debugging information out of Bluez by default.

If you were to insert more debugging code into the source code of Bluez, you would of course have to recompile and install it, there is no way around that. Since Bluez isn't really that big, it shouldn't be a problem though. I would suggest downloading the newest version from [here](http://www.bluez.org/), then insert your debugging code, do `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`.